# Update MongoDB document after some of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongodb model called activity with (`totalHours`, `totalFocusDay`, `totalActiveDay`, and `updatedAt`).

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const activitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  totalHours: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  totalFocusDay: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  totalActiveDay: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
},
{
  timestamps: true,
}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Activity", activitySchema);
```

I want to make the activity docs updated after every day to set totalFocusDays with zero if the updatedAt was from 24 hours or one day.

How i can do that?

I have tried to use aggregates but didn't work.

Comment: Since `totalFocusDay` is derived from `updatedAt`, is it possible to not include it in the model and instead calculate this when reading a Activity document? This can avoid redundnacy and possibly reduce writes.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you actually mean. Are you looking for a batch update query or do you want to set `totalFocusDay` only when the `Activity` document is updated? It would help if you give a scenario of what you want to happen with perhaps a sample document with your desired outcome.

Comment: What did you try, and what "didn't work" about it?